# Angular Deactivate property are not access in Deactivate guard, for the child Presentational component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

-----Parent component is lazy loaded like below ---

```
VieweditpurchaseComponent-- (parent)
```

EditPurchaseDetailsComponent (child component )

```
<hrs-app-edit-purchase-details *ngIf="currentProduct$ | async" [getCurrentProduct]="currentProduct$ | async"></hrs-app-edit-purchase-details>
```

Deactivate guard---

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanDeactivate, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { EditPurchaseDetailsComponent } from '../../components/edit-purchase-details/edit-purchase-details.component'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PurchaseAddeditGuard implements CanDeactivate<EditPurchaseDetailsComponent> {
  canDeactivate(component: EditPurchaseDetailsComponent, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, currentState: RouterStateSnapshot, nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot | undefined): boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
    debugger
    if (component.isDirty) { ----this says undefined
      console.log("you will lose data");
      return false;
    }
    
    return true
  }
  
}
```

```
RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: '', component: PurchaseComponent  },
      { path: 'purchaselists', component: ViewPurchaseDetailsComponent },
      { path: 'vieweditpurchase', component: VieweditpurchaseComponent, canDeactivate:[PurchaseAddeditGuard] }
    ]),
```

ISSUE : in the deactivate guard i am not able to access my child component property, hence the guard is not working. how do i approach deactivate on this kind of app structure

Comment: The component in the guard is `EditPurchaseDetailsComponent` but the component in the route is `VieweditpurchaseComponent` -- could this be why?

Comment: i have added a guard to my parent component, because my child component doesn't have the route. it's inside of my parent component

Comment: In this case I don't think you will be able to access child component properties unless you pass them up from the child component to the parent

Comment: thanks for your reply, but the things is i tried that way also, again issue in that too like,

for the first time if i make any changes in the form and try navigate away CanDeactivate is works fine, but if undo the changes in the form and navigate away, then CanDeactive should return true right?, thats not happening.

<========================================================>
i am looking to implement CanDeactive  guard below template strcuture
<parenthtml>
<child></child>
</parenthtml>

all the form fields are in the child component

Comment: As long as you are passing the needed data up from the child component to the parent one so that it can be accessed in the guard, it should work